# Sending a blob from Salesforce in a HTTP request?

Tags: apex, http, blob

Documentation says we can't do this. So as the title says, is there a workaround to make this possible?

Comment: It is possible, I did send multipart attachment using Http Request. Following link helped me http://enreeco.blogspot.it/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html#finalCode_multipart

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the setBodyAsBlob(Blob someBlob) method on HttpRequest to send a raw blob in an HTTP request. If you need to send a mime multi-part request, then that's harder as there's no good way to glue together the string mime part headers and the binary data (you can at this point, base64 encode the payload to work around that).

Comment: I take it `setBodyAsBlob` is a relatively new addition to the language? I don't remember seeing it before.

Comment: March 2012 http://www.pocketsoap.com/weblog/2012/03/1850.html