# Posting multiple files from Apex code to an external service

Tags: apex, post, form

The question on how to post binary data to an external service from Apex has been answered on SFSE already, and I'm aware of that. However,  what I'm trying to do, is to optimize a process by posting multiple objects to an external service in one POST request. I've reused the previous answers, with a little of bit tweaking it. However, my test server always gets only the first part.:S Do you have any idea where's('re) the bug(s)?

```
public with sharing class FileUploader {
public FileUploader() {

}

public static void upload(List<FeedItem> files) {
    System.debug('upload');

    String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';
    String reqEndPoint = 'https://localhost:8080/dummy-endpoint';

    String allPartsEncoded = '';

    for (Integer i = 1; i < files.size(); i++) {        
        allPartsEncoded += encode(
            files.get(i), 
            'file' + i,
            boundary, 
            i == files.size() - 1
        );
    }

    Blob bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(allPartsEncoded);

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(reqEndPoint);
    req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
    req.setTimeout(120000);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
}

private static String encode(FeedItem file, String partName, String boundary, Boolean isLastPart) {
    System.debug('Encoding file with name ' + file.ContentFileName);
    System.debug('boundary = ' + boundary);
    System.debug('isLastPart = ' + isLastPart);

    Blob file_body = file.ContentData;
    String file_name = file.ContentFileName;


    // Repost of code  with fix for file corruption issue
    // Orignal code postings and explanations
    // http://enreeco.blogspot.in/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html
    // http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/post-multipart-without-base64-encoding-the-body
    // Additional changes commented GW: that fix issue with occasional corruption of files        
    String header = '--' + boundary
                    + '\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ' 
                    + 'name="' + partName + '"; '
                    + 'filename="' + file_name
                    + '";\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream';

    String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header + '\r\n\r\n'));
    while (headerEncoded.endsWith('=')) {
        header += ' ';
        headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header + '\r\n\r\n'));
    }

    // GW: Do not prepend footer with \r\n, you'll see why in a moment
    // String footer = '\r\n--'+boundary+'--';
    String footer = '--' + boundary;
    if (isLastPart) {
        footer += '--';
    }

    String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file_body);
    // GW: Do not encode footer yet
    // String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));

    String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length() - 4, bodyEncoded.length());

    // GW: replacement section to get rid of padding without corrupting data
    if (last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
        // The '==' sequence indicates that the last group contained only one 8 bit byte
        // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
        // 8 digit binary representation of LF is 00001010
        // Stitch them together and then from the right split them into 6 bit chunks
        // 0000110100001010 becomes 0000 110100 001010
        // Note the first 4 bits 0000 are identical to the padding used to encode the
        // second original 6 bit chunk, this is handy it means we can hard code the response in
        // The decimal values of 110100 001010 are 52 10
        // The base64 mapping values of 52 10 are 0 K
        // See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 for base64 mapping table
        // Therefore, we replace == with 0K
        // Note: if using \n\n instead of \r\n replace == with 'oK'
        last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0, 2) + '0K';
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0, bodyEncoded.length() - 4) + last4Bytes;
        // We have appended the \r\n to the Blob, so leave footer as it is.            
    } else if (last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
        // '=' indicates that encoded data already contained two out of 3x 8 bit bytes
        // We replace final 8 bit byte with a CR e.g. \r
        // 8 digit binary representation of CR is 00001101
        // Ignore the first 2 bits of 00 001101 they have already been used up as padding
        // for the existing data.
        // The Decimal value of 001101 is 13
        // The base64 value of 13 is N
        // Therefore, we replace = with N
        // Note: if using \n instead of \r replace = with 'K'
        last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0, 3) + 'N';
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0, bodyEncoded.length() - 4) + last4Bytes;
        // We have appended the CR e.g. \r, still need to prepend the line feed to the footer
        footer = '\n' + footer;                     
    } else {
        // Prepend the CR LF to the footer
        footer = '\r\n' + footer;
    }
    System.debug('header =' + header);
    System.debug('footer =' + footer);

    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));

    return headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded;
}
```

}

Comment: Perhaps your could grab your blob and try posting it using some other method so you can examine the data transfer.