# Multipart form data post file with multiple form parameters?

Tags: apex, callout, httprequest, blob

I am gone through [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/post-multipart-without-base64-encoding-the-body/33326#33326) and wanted to add one more form data parameter, but when I am sending a request that parameter it not getting posted into form data, please advise what I am missing.

Here is my code.

```
Attachment objPDF = [SELECT ID, Name, Body FROM Attachment where id = '00P0I00000u85YXUAY'
    LIMIT 1
];
String strTargetURL = 'https://www.perfectaudit.com/api/v1/book/upload';

String boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW';
string header1 = '--' + boundary + '\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="pk"';
String header1Encoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header1 + '\r\n\r\n'));
while (header1Encoded.endsWith('=')) {
    header1 += ' ';
    header1Encoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header1 + '\r\n\r\n'));
}
String body1Encoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('68749\r\n'));
String last4Bytes = body1Encoded.substring(body1Encoded.length() - 4, body1Encoded.length());
if (last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0, 2) + '0K';
    body1Encoded = body1Encoded.substring(0, body1Encoded.length() - 4) + last4Bytes;    
} else if (last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0, 3) + 'N';
    body1Encoded = body1Encoded.substring(0, body1Encoded.length() - 4) + last4Bytes;    
}

String header = '--' + boundary + '\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="' + objPDF.Name + '";\nContent-Type: application/pdf';
String footer = '--' + boundary + '--';
String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header + '\r\n\r\n'));
while (headerEncoded.endsWith('=')) {
    header += ' ';
    headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header + '\r\n\r\n'));
}
String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf('This is text file'));
Blob bodyBlob = null;
last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length() - 4, bodyEncoded.length());
if (last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0, 2) + '0K';
    bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0, bodyEncoded.length() - 4) + last4Bytes;
    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
    bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(header1Encoded + body1Encoded + headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);    
} else if (last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
    last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0, 3) + 'N';
    bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0, bodyEncoded.length() - 4) + last4Bytes;
    footer = '\r\n' + footer;
    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
    bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(header1Encoded + body1Encoded + headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);    
} else {
    footer = '\n' + footer;
    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
    bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(header1Encoded + body1Encoded + headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);    
}

HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

String userName = 'xxxxx';
String password = 'xxxxx';
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(userName + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setEndpoint(strTargetURL);
req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
req.setTimeout(120000);

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

I want to do below request using apex.

```
POST /api/v1/book/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: www.perfectaudit.com
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 356b00b1-0d9e-5332-1c80-c5b08ba3e49a
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pk"

68749
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="ticketmsrtc_18112017.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

I am able to post a file but "pk" parameter is missing from form data.

Payload:-

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pk"  

68749

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"; filename="eStmt_2017-11-30 (1).pdf";
Content-Type: application/pdf  

***PDF DATA***
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: You might want to decode and debug what the payload looks like. Your code is sufficiently complicated enough that it may be something simple, but hard to spot without seeing what an example payload looks like.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for your time, I have updated my Question with decoded payload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid manually handling the Base64 encoding yourself and the application of [Grant Wickman's solution](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/33326/102) to avoid padding characters on the binary data before the multipart boundary.

I looked at this in some detail in relation to [sending multipart/formdata messages to the Einstein Vision Services](http://www.fishofprey.com/2017/04/steps-required-to-support-posting.html).

Instead, use something like the [HttpFormBuilder](https://github.com/MetaMind/apex-utils/blob/master/HttpFormBuilder.apex) that MetaMind provided. It will provide a much more consistent application of the `CR` `LF` allocation between the part data/bytes and the multipart boundary.