# Sending multipart data throws error?

Tags: apex, integration, callout

I am using exact answer from this link, just with some minor modification.

[Post multipart without Base64 Encoding the body](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24108/post-multipart-without-base64-encoding-the-body/33326#33326)

I have developed a spring boot application which accepts two formdata, one is 
 multipart as param and the other is string . I have marked attributes both as required 'true'.

I have hosted the app in heroku so that you all can also try. It works well with any rest client like this:

[image]

My Apex version :

```
public static void uploadFile(Blob file_body, String file_name, String reqEndPoint){
    String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';
    String header = '--'+boundary+'\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file";metadata="test me Apex"; filename="'+file_name+'"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream'; // added '\r's removed ';' see Tim Smith's comment
    String footer = '--'+boundary+'--';
    String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
    while(headerEncoded.endsWith('='))
    {
        header+=' ';
        headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
    }
    String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file_body);
    Blob bodyBlob = null;
    String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length()-4,bodyEncoded.length());
    if(last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
        last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
    } else if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
        last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
        bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
        footer = '\n' + footer;
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
    } else {
        footer = '\r\n' + footer;
        String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded+bodyEncoded+footerEncoded);
    }

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundary);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(reqEndPoint);
    req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
    req.setTimeout(120000);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug('res -> '+res.getBody());
}
```

When I try to hit it via Anonymous apex:

```
Attachment attachment = [SELECT Id, Body, Name FROM Attachment WHERE Id = '00P7F00000BnUX2UAN'];
Test.uploadFile(attachment.Body, attachment.Name, 'https://localrestapi.herokuapp.com/consumeFiles');
```

The debug statement print like this :

```
21:15:37.942 (1942954579)|USER_DEBUG|[108]|DEBUG|res -> <html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Thu Jul 04 15:45:38 UTC 2019</div><div>There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).</div><div>Required String parameter &#39;metadata&#39; is not present</div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a post and example here :

[Multipart form data post file with multiple form parameters?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211477/multipart-form-data-post-file-with-multiple-form-parameters)

To post multiple form data I used this and it worked . basically we have to add boundary after each form data.

```
public static void uploadFile(Blob file_body, String file_name, String reqEndPoint){

    //callout ePOR service
    string contentType = vNHttpFormBuilder.GetContentType();

    //  Compose the form
    string form64 = '';
    //******This was the boundary I was missing****
    form64 += vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
    form64 += vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteBodyParameter('metadata', 'Test me');
    form64 += vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary();
    form64 += vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteBlobBodyParameter('filename', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(file_body), file_name);
    form64 += vNHttpFormBuilder.WriteBoundary(null);
    blob formBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(form64);
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setEndpoint(reqEndPoint);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    req.setBodyAsBlob(formBlob);
    req.setTimeout(120000);

    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug('res -> '+res.getBody());
}
```